# Remove an item from an IEnumerable<T> collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a popuplated `IEnumerable<User>` collection.

I want to remove an item from it, how can I do this?

```
foreach(var u in users)
{
  if(u.userId = 1123)
  {
    // remove!
  }
}
```

I know your not suppose to remove while looping, so I don't mind either creating a new collection or removing it after.

But I don't know how to remove an item, kind of lost for some reason on this!

Alternately which I am confused on also, how can I create a new collection like:

```
IEnumerable<User> modifiedUsers = new List<User>();

foreach(var u in users)
{
   if(u.userId != 1233)
   {
        modifiedUsers.add ??????
   }
}
```

How can I add to the collection?

Comment: Btw, while iterating over a list you can not remove elements without getting a runtime error. Like Tilak showed in his answer, the list must be copied prior to enumeration.

Answer (score 82):

Not removing but creating a new `List` without that element with LINQ:

```
// remove
users = users.Where(u => u.userId != 123).ToList();

// new list
var modified = users.Where(u => u.userId == 123).ToList();
```

Comment: You are creating a new list in both cases. The first example just overwrites the reference.

Comment: Your terminology is not correct. You are not removing an item from the list, In both examples you create a new list and the old list remains unaffected. You are merely overwriting the reference in your first example, as such stating that it results in a `remove` is incorrect. You should update your question to clarify that.

Comment: Clearly the title and author wants to REMOVE the item, not create a new list without it...

Comment: Whilst this was useful to me, I just want to point out that the Author asked for removing item from IEnumerable<T> , therefore the suffix ".ToList()" in the examples is not necessary. (Though probably what a lot of people who end up on this page are after.)

Comment: Always use `AsList()` instead of `ToList()`

Answer (score 38):

You can not remove an item from an `IEnumerable`; it can only be enumerated, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx

You have to use an `ICollection` if you want to add and remove items. Maybe you can try and casting your `IEnumerable`; this will off course only work if the underlying object implements ICollection`.

See here for more on `ICollection`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

You can, of course, just create a new list from your IEnumerable, as pointed out by lante, but this might be "sub optimal", depending on your actual use case, of course.

`ICollection` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 13):

Try turning the `IEnumerable` into a `List`. From this point on you will be able to use `List`'s `Remove` method to remove items.

To pass it as a param to the `Remove` method using Linq you can get the item by the following methods:

- `users.Single(x => x.userId == 1123)`
- `users.First(x => x.userId == 1123)`

The code is as follows:

```
users = users.ToList(); // Get IEnumerable as List

users.Remove(users.First(x => x.userId == 1123)); // Remove item

// Finished
```

Comment: but can I assign it to something that expects an ienumerable afterwords?  do I have to restart it to the beginning?

Comment: @user1361315 of course, List implements IEnumerable, so you can indeed assing it to an IEnumerable

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this:

```
users = users.Where(x => x.userId != userIdToRemove);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `IEnumerable<T>` can only be iterated.

In your second example, you can remove from original collection by iterating over a copy of it

```
foreach(var u in users.ToArray()) // ToArray creates a copy
{
   if(u.userId != 1233)
   {
        users.Remove(u);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove `IEnumerable<T>` elements, but you can use the [Enumerable.Skip Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerable` interface is just that, enumerable - it doesn't provide any methods to `Add` or `Remove` or modify the list at all.

The interface just provides a way to iterate over some items - most implementations that require enumeration will implement `IEnumerable` such as `List<T>`

Why don't you just use your code without the implicit cast to `IEnumerable`

```
// Treat this like a list, not an enumerable
List<User> modifiedUsers = new List<User>();

foreach(var u in users)
{
   if(u.userId != 1233)
   {
        // Use List<T>.Add
        modifiedUsers.Add(u);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to modify it, then pass it to something that expects a ienumerable.

Comment: Then modify it and pass it - there is no reason you can't pass a `List<T>` to a method that's expecting an `IEnumerable<T>` since `List<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`. I don't even think you need a cast due to covariance rules.

Answer (score -3):

users.toList().RemoveAll(user => <your condition>)

Comment: this will take your whole list into memory due to the .ToList(). This should be avoided at all costs

Comment: This will only remove the elements from the newly created list, not the original enumerable

Answer (score -4):

There is now an extension method to convert the `IEnumerable<>` to a `Dictionary<,>` which then has a `Remove` method.

```
public readonly IEnumerable<User> Users = new User[]; // or however this would be initialized

// To take an item out of the collection
Users.ToDictionary(u => u.Id).Remove(1123);

// To take add an item to the collection
Users.ToList().Add(newuser);
```