# Iterator and IEnumerator

Tags: c#, arraylist

C#'s IEnumerator doesn't have a next() and remove() how do I solve this?
(hitScans is an ArrayList)

```
// Iterator it = enemyWaves.iterator();
   IEnumerator it = hitScans.GetEnumerator();
         while (it.MoveNext())
            {
                if ((dist = ((ew = (EnemyWave)it.next()).distanceTraveled += ew.bulletVelocity)
                - myLocation.distance(ew.fireLocation)) > 50)
                {
                    it.remove();
                    continue;
                }
```

and

```
// Iterator i = hitScans.iterator();
   IEnumerator i = hitScans.GetEnumerator();
                while (i.MoveNext())
                {
                    double[] scan = (double[])i.next();
```

Comment: How do you solve *what*?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot IEnumerator doesn't have next() and remove(); as far as I know it doesn't have any methods similar.  So what do I do to make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realy need use Iterator/Enumerator??

If you just need to remove elements from ArrayList while iterating it (whitch is commonly discussed issue), I would propose something like this:

```
for (int i=hitScans.Count-1;i>=0;i--){
   if (/*your difficult condition*/){
      hitScans.RemoveAt(i);   
   }
}
```

and for the second part:
foreach - isn't it solution?

Comment: That might work, do you know of something to replace next()?

Comment: yep. Edited answer. foreach could help I think

Comment: Did you forget to put in the foreach version?

Comment: I didn't put that because I didn't get what you want to get from hitScans using IEnumerator

Comment: @Jacklyn Note that with a `foreach`, you cannot modify the collection. So no removing allowed. A `for` loop does work, if you work backward (as in this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 'remove', there is no direct .NET equivalent since IEnumerable is not intended to be modifiable. There are some work-arounds:
[Want to remove an item from a IEnumerable<T> collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143438/want-to-remove-an-item-from-a-ienumerablet-collection)

Regarding 'next', note that even though each of 'hasNext' and 'next' are not equivalent to C# 'MoveNext' and 'Current', when used together they produce the same effect.

e.g.,

```
Iterator it = enemyWaves.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next();
}
```

will typically convert to the following C# code:

```
IEnumerator it = enemyWaves.GetEnumerator();    
while (it.MoveNext())
{
    object o = it.Current;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I have to use a for loop as MisterMe said

Comment: @Jacklyn: Yes - I don't think you can remove an item in the standard MoveNext/Current loop.